# MySQL not updating row which clearly exists

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I make an update query:

```
update sometable set somecolumn1='value' where somecolumn2 = 'value'
```

in `phpMyAdmin` it says `0 rows affected. ( Query took 0.0048 sec )`

but when I do:

```
select * from sometable where somecolumn2 = 'value'
```

a row is returned, meaning it does exist. Why isn't the row then getting updated?

Comment: Probably because the row is already set to the exact values you are setting it to. It will say `0 rows affected` in that case.

Comment: Well spot! MySQL is cleverer than I thought

Comment: Yeah. It's not entirely intuitive - I think it should always show `1 row affected`. But well.

Answer (score 1):

The row is already set to the same value you are trying to set.
So mysql does not need to update and tells you zero rows affected.
In the case where only 1 row can be affected, mysql should tell you that the row is already set to that value.

Pekka got this correctly answered but should put under "answer" instead of comment so that the question will no longer appear in the unanswered section of stack overflow. :)